# Print a pdf downloaded through a webservice in Flutter / Dart

Tags: pdf, flutter, dart, printing

I'm working with Flutter.
I have a pdf document that I download from a webservice.
The http body response of this pdf sent by [http package](https://pub.dev/packages/http) is typed as Uint8List.
Then, I would like to print it with [printing](https://pub.dev/packages/printing) which is working with [pdf](https://pub.dev/packages/pdf) package.

So I need an instance of a PdfDocument from this class.
Is there a way that I can convert this Uint8List to pdf ? I tried some other dart packages, but they didn't answer my needs because I need to print pdf, not just view them.

I also looked with [flutter_downloader](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_downloader) in order to simply get pdf file without bothering myself with Uint8List, but it seems the package is not working at the moment: https://github.com/fluttercommunity/flutter_downloader/issues/132

Thank you very much for answering.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use:

```
var data = await getThePdfData(); // obtain the Uint8List
Printing.sharePdf(bytes: data);
```

Comment: Im also having same issue. But the solution given here is only to share the pdf. I want to print pdf file. How can i print it?

Comment: @VickyM did you found any solution to print pdf files?